# If "Not X Is Nothing Then" replacement in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

When we want to check not null in vb.net we use  "IF Not X Is Nothing Then" but this is very vague to read and understand especially if code is complicated or large. Is there any condition with which we can check the same condition and easy to read or understand?

Comment: The `IsNot` operator has been available in VB for quite a while now, so you should be using `If X IsNot Nothing Then`.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
If X IsNot Nothing Then
```

reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/isnot-operator

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. 
As suggested by other comments/answers you can use the `IsNot` operator.
Or you can use the `IsNothing()` function. E.g.

```
If Not IsNothing(someObject) Then ...
```

You can also use the `Iif()` function but I don't recommend it since it don't do short-circuiting and always evaluates all the arguments, regardless of the condition.

Probably [the inline if](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator) is what you're looking for (available since VB.NET 2008 onward):

```
If(condition, truePart, falsePart)
```